# which scale is used in Nirvana's "Love Buzz"?

Tags: scales

which scale is used in Nirvana's "Love Buzz"?
is this an eastern scale?
how is it possible to mix an eastern scale and a western rhythm?
which scale should be used in its baseline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the [phrygian dominant scale](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Phrygian_dominant_scale), whose composition is (starting from E for example's sake):

**Notes**:      E   F   G#  A   B   C   D
**Intervals**:  1   b2  3   4   5   b6  b7

Addressing your other questions:

> is this an eastern scale?

Wikipedia article says:

> This scale occurs in Indian, Middle Eastern, Eastern European, Central Asian, and Flamenco music. It is common in Arabic and Egyptian music [...]

So yes it is.

> how is it possible to mix an eastern scale and a western rhythm?

Like in the very track you mentioned for instance ;)) Or in [Dick Dale music](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V4eEqN4HY7Q) as a more famous example.

> which scale should be used in its baseline?

I assume you ask about on top of which *chords* can you play this scale. You can work it out yourself by observing its third stacks, here you have an E-based reference:

```
E7  FMaj7   G#dim   Ammaj7  Bm7b5   CMaj7#5 Dm7
```